# population - central limit theorem

Tags: probability

27% of all Americans earn 100K+.  In a city of 2000 people, What is the probability that there will be between 500 and 600 earning 100K+.

My solution:

a = (500-2000(.27))/(square root of 2000(.27)(.73)) = -40/square root of 394.2 = -2.01466

b = (600-2000(.27))/(square root of 2000(.27)(.73)) = 60/square root of 394.2 = 3.022

Then I plug in the values into this site:  http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/z_table.html

and get 0.9768

Is this correct?  Thank you.

Comment: The statement of your question is unclear.  If I interpret your question literally, then exactly 540 people in the group of 2000 earn more than 100K, so the probability that between 500 and 600 people in the group earn more than 100K is exactly 1.  Any probabilistic interpretation of your question requires a rephrasing because I have no indication of whether 2000 represents a randomly selected sample.  If not, then no sample size is indicated.  I also cannot tell if 27% represents a parameter or a sample proportion.

Comment: Thank you for that. I did further clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

We may regard the sample as consisting of 2000 independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with individual probability of success $p = 0.27$.  The sum of these is binomial with parameters $n = 2000$ and $p = 0.27$, so let us denote the random number of individuals from the sample that earn more than 100K by $X$. Therefore, the *exact* probability that $X$ is between $500$ and $600$ is $$\Pr[500 \le X \le 600] = \sum_{x=500}^{600} \binom{2000}{x}(0.27)^x (1-0.27)^{2000-x}.$$  This of course is not an easy sum to calculate without a computer, so we approximate the distribution of $X$ with a suitable normal distribution, say $Y$, whose mean and variance are equal to the mean and variance of $X$, respectively.  Thus $$\begin{align*} {\rm E}[Y] &= np = 2000(0.27) = 540 = \mu, \\ {\rm Var}[Y] &= np(1-p) = 2000(0.27)(1-0.27) = 394.2 = \sigma^2.\end{align*}$$  But since $Y$ is a continuous variable and $X$ is discrete, an appropriate continuity correction is required:  $$\Pr[500 \le X \le 600] \approx \Pr[499.5 \le Y \le 600.5]$$ since the extra $0.5$ on each end will ensure the coverage of the entire probability masses at $X = 500$ and $X = 600$.  Now we standardize $Y$:  $$\Pr[499.5 \le Y \le 600.5] = \Pr\biggl[\frac{499.5 - 540}{\sqrt{394.2}} \le \frac{Y - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{600.5 - 540}{\sqrt{394.2}}\biggr].$$  The resulting probability is approximately $0.978162$, which compares favorably to the exact probability, which is $0.97866966408678077689\ldots$.

**Note.** Your calculation is mathematically consistent, but does not incorporate the continuity correction, which is why the probability you obtained, $0.976774$, is not as good an approximation.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time.